# Div background change when hovering another div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, background-position

I am trying to get this working but I know very little of jQuery.

When an user hovers on the div "button" the background position of the div "slide" must change from "0 0" to "0 -89px", while moving the mouse to another point must reset the background position to "0 0".

That's the code (recycled from another question on stackoverflow):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').hover(function(){
        $('#slide').css('backgroundPosition', newValue);
    }, function(){
        $('#slide').css('backgroundPosition', '0 -89px');
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="slide"></div>
        <div id="button">Click me!</div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
div#slide {
  background: url(base_slide.png) no-repeat;
  width: 629px;
  height: 89px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

It works, but not as expected. When I hover on the button div nothing happens, but If I move my mouse to another point all the code works and the background changes.

I am sure that there is a possibility to fix this but I just started yesterday to explore some jQuery. Also I don't know how to reset the background position to 0 0.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the var newValue should be replaced by '0 0'. If I understand your needs correctly.

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/VBEaQ/1/

Update:
Here is a full example with fadeIn fadeOut effect ;-)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').hover(function(){
        $('#slide').stop().fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 -89px');
        }).fadeIn();
    }, function(){
        $('#slide').stop().fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
        }).fadeIn();
    });
});​
```

Live demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/VBEaQ/9/

Comment: That's what I needed.
Now I understand: the first newValue sets the new backgroundposition, while the second one the original backgroundposition.
Thank you very much.

Comment: If it doesn't take to much time for you, could you explain me if is it possible to achieve this transiction with a fadeIn and a fadeOut effect? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

you should try to define multiple css attributes and values instead of 1 function = 1 css method that you use. The jquery documentation should help.. also its background-position not backgroundPosition.

Comment: You are wrong, jquery offers two way of defining css, in the form used here, he is defining a javascript variable whose name is indeed backgroundPosition, he's not defining the css property directly. 
On the other hand, if you use an object literal with the css function of jquery, there you can use the actual css property name. The jQuery doc should help you too ;-)