# jQuery slider > fade slides onscreen instead of animate()

Tags: jquery, slider

I've modified this slider script so that instead of animating the slides from right to left, they just appear one on top of another. What would I need to do to apply a dissolve/fade effect?

In other words, I want to fade the previous slide off as the next slide appears

```
 a.fn.calculateSlidePos = function () {
            var b = 2;
            a(this).find("dt").not(":first").each(function () {
                var c = dtWidth * activeID;
                if (b <= activeID) {
                    var d = dtWidth * (b - 1);
                    /*a(this).animate({left: d});*/
                    a(this).css({left: d});
                    if (b < activeID) {
                       a(this).next().fadeIn().css({
                            left: d + dtWidth
                        })
                    } else {
                        /*a(this).next().animate({left: c})*/
                        a(this).next().css({left: c})
                    }
                } else {
                    var e = dlWidth - dtWidth * (slideTotal - b + 1);
                    a(this).animate({
                        left: e
                    });
                    var f = e + dtWidth;
                    /*a(this).next().animate({left: f})*/
                    a(this).next().css({left: f})
                }
                b = b + 1
            });
            setTimeout(function () {
                a(".easy-accordion").find("dd").not(".active").each(function () {
                    a(this).css({
                        display: "none"
                    })
                })
            }, 400)
        };
```

Comment: check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10161955/925854 and let me know if it answers your question correctly ;)

Comment: Thanks Liuti. I'm not sure exactly how to apply your answer to my problem but I've given it a few tries with no luck.

Comment: I don't quite understand.  `easy-accordion` seems to have tabbed slides that slide in/out.  How would fading work in this case?  You still want the tabs on the side?

Comment: @Jeff B: No, I've forked the code and have it configurable to do tabs or no tabs. Also added arrows and dots to show current slide position, etc. Just cant figure the fadeIn, fadeOut behavior.

Comment: Any way you could put this in a jsfiddle?  It's hard to comment on code without seeing your markup, the rest of the code, etc.

Comment: @ScottB: It demonstrates a fadeIn - fadeOut behavior. +1 to the jsfiddle example ;-)